# Cache problems when updating an object from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, model

I have a problem with making changes to an object from within another model as well as within the object's model. I have the following models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  def do_something
    self.value -= 1
    # Complicated code doing other things to this Foo

    bars[0].do_other

    save!
  end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  def do_other
    foo.value += 2
    foo.save!
  end
end
```

If I have a `Foo` object with `value` set to 1, and call `do_something` on it, I can see from my database logs the following two operations:

```
Foo Update (0.0s) UPDATE "foos" SET "value" = 2 WHERE "id" = 1
Foo Update (0.0s) UPDATE "foos" SET "value" = 0 WHERE "id" = 1
```

... so do_something is presumably caching the `self` object. Can I avoid this, other than by moving the `save!`s around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides a [`reload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002344) method for reloading the attributes of a model object from the database. The source code for this method is:

```
# File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2687
def reload(options = nil)
  clear_aggregation_cache
  clear_association_cache
  @attributes.update(self.class.find(self.id, options).instance_variable_get('@attributes'))
  @attributes_cache = {}
  self
end
```

—As you can see it calls a `clear_association_cache` method, so there's definitely caching of associations going on which would explain the behaviour you're seeing. You should probably reload the model in one of your methods prior to saving.

Comment: What are associations in this context? Also, if I reload the object, does that override any local unsaved changes?

Comment: Apparently not. Ok, this works - although I'm still not sure to what association refers.

Comment: Ah, brain fade. It's the has_many, belongs_to decorator, isn't it?